How do pass data from a http get to a widget on another file flutter
Hello i have a flutter program structured like so: In this code i have a Navigation Bar with 3 pages, To make the code cleaner, i decided to write the code of the 3 pages in each of their own separate file. But i need to have access to the response of a HTTP GET request that was called in the main.dart file. Now although its possible to do the GET request in each file, but that would seem inefficient because the GET request will be unnecessarily repeated since its the same data
lib
  screens
    home_screen.dart
    profile_screen.dart
    truck_screen.dart
  main.dart

main.dart
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:iconsax_flutter/iconsax_flutter.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart';

import 'screens/home_screen.dart';
import 'screens/profile_screen.dart';
import 'screens/truck_screen.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Bottom Navigation Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  var _jsonData = [];
  final url = "https:xxxxxxx";
  
  //HTTP GET REQUEST
  void getItems() async {
    try {
      final response = await get(Uri.parse(url));
      final jsonResponse = jsonDecode(response.body) as List;

      setState(() {
        //Store the response in _jsonData
        _jsonData = jsonResponse;
      });
    } catch (err) {}
  }

  @override
  void initState(){
    super.initState();
    getItems();
  }

  int _currentIndex = 0;
  final List<Widget> _tabs = [
    HomeScreen(),
    TruckScreen(),
    ProfileScreen(),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('Bottom Navigation Demo'),
      ),
      body: _tabs[_currentIndex],
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
        currentIndex: _currentIndex,
        onTap: (int index) {
          setState(() {
            _currentIndex = index;
          });
        },
        items: [
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Iconsax.home), label: "Home"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Iconsax.truck), label: "Trucks"),
          BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Iconsax.user), label: "Me"),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}

truck_screen.dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class TruckScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const TruckScreen({super.key});
  
  //Code to somehow have access to _jsonData in the main file.
  final _masterData = _jsonDataFromTheOtherFile; //Wrong Code of course

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: _masterData.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, i) {
          final row = _masterData[i];
          return Text("Name: ${row["truckName"]}");
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}

What would be the cleanest way of passing the response data to the other files?

I would use Provider to share data between screens

@rstrelba a sample code that is close to my use case would be greatly appreciated, it helps me understand how its used faster.

readying about provider, and it would seem its counterpart riverpod seems to be much easier for me to understand. though im still figuring it out how to make it work

in main.dart you wrap your MaterialApp  with ChangeNotifierProvider
 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ChangeNotifierProvider(
      create: (context) => MyState(), 
      lazy: false,
      child: MaterialApp(
              home: NewsUI(),
      ),
    );
  }

MyState is a class with your shared data
class MyState with ChangeNotifier {
  SomeType data1 ;

  MyState();
}

In ANY build functions of your widgets you can get access to MyState's data
    @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        if (_loading) return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
        var myState = Provider.of<MyState>(context, listen: false);
        myState.data1 ...

